# Object reference not set to an instance of an object : Upon calling controller B's method that has session , from controller A

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, session

I noticed that if I have a session variable inside a method in a Controller , say Controller B and I call it from controller A. I get the following error:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

**Controller A:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   Session["name"] = "sam";
   return View();
}

public ActionResult About()
{
     ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";
     DefaultController d = new DefaultController();
     d.MethodB();
     return View();
}
```

**Controller B:**

```
 public void MethodB()
 {
   string name = Session["name"].ToString();
 }
```

**Steps:**

1. Call controller A's Index()
2. Call controller A's About()

Although, I am probably not ever going to do this but I would like to understand this behavior out of curiosity.